# Java, which data storage type is used typical

Tags: java

I want local store some user (username,password) on disk and in the next step maybe informations about the user(birthday,gender,...).
I work whith Eclipse and use Java as language.

There should be local file with a structure for storage.I also can use a txt-file and storage the informations like this:

> username1,pasword1;username2,password2;

But this is not good if you want add more informations.

Some criteria which guillaume girod-vitouchkina assumed (thank you!)

The data:

- is stored local on a single pc
- is used just for the login
- is not used other programs
- is going to be read at the start of the program
- should be not modify by other people
- is not used for server-stuff

I googled a bit and found out that XML,JSON might be a possible solution but not sure which one is typical format used in a Java projects for this kind of stuff.

Thanks :)

Comment: But you want to store it in program or on disk?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking which data representation is popular in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **no** *typical* data storage type, there are several designs and tools.

And Java can use almost every kind of storage, using wrappers or gateways if needed.

When I see your datas, it is like a directory, with confidential datas (password). Nowadays, nobody stores passwords in clear !

But as *usual*, it depends on what you want to do:

- you want to store, yes, but do you want to read your datas: by who, by what program, frequently or not ?
- is it critical datas ? can you lose them ?
- do you change them regularly, or never ?
- if you change them, do you want to keep old datas, or traces of changes ?
- everybody can see your datas ? everybody can modify them, can delete them ? What about security ?
- what kind of architecture do you have ? a single PC, a server, local ? Is it for a web app ?
- after that, you can think about format, locale, ...

After all, you can put them in a file like you do, of course, or enhance it a little or a lot.

Hope it helps.